# adding href to anchor tag not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have the below anchor tag defined in ui bootstrap js file.

```
    <a class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" accordion-      
   transclude="heading">
```

I need to add href tag to the above anchor tag for meeting the accessibility concerns.
As that is as part of vendor js file, I cant add href directly there.
Hence I tried to add href attribute using jquery to the above anchor tag as

```
    $('.accordion-toggle').attr('href', '#')
```

the above line of code worked fine in chrome and firefox but did not work in internet explorer and even the toggle functionality is lost.May I know whether we can get href to the above anchor tag.

Thanks,
Balaji

Comment: Why would you add an anchor tag via jquery when you are using angular?

Comment: yeah i can do it with angular too, but my issue is like im able to add href attribute however in internet explorer the toggle functionality got affected in internet explorer

Comment: Do you have more than one .accordion-toggle element on the page?

Comment: Is it Angular bootstrap? it is very flexible. You can just replace any tpl in $templteCache with your own.

Comment: oh is it, let me try that , thanks for your reply

Comment: just one thing if I add that, the toggle functionality is getting affected in internet explorer after adding the href attribute ,any idea on that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('.accordion-toggle').click(function() {

     window.location.href = '#';

});
```

instead.